# How do I populate a list box in c++ builder with the available themed styles?

Tags: c++, c++builder

How do I populate a list box in c++ builder with the available themed styles?

I performed this task like so in Delphi XE8:

```
{*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Procedure: StylesListRefresh
  Author:    Mr. Arch Brooks, Software Engineer, Brooks Computing Systems LLC
  Date:      06-Aug-2015
  @Param     None
  @Return    None
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}

procedure TTopFormStylesC.StylesListRefresh;
var
  styleName : string;
begin
  lbxStyles.Items.Clear;
  for stylename in TStyleManager.StyleNames do
  begin
    lbxStyles.Items.Add(stylename);
  end;
end;
```

Here is my c++ Builder source code:

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#include <string>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "TopFormStylesu.h"
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
using namespace std;
TTopFormStyles *TopFormStyles;
// TTopFormStyles *StylesRefresh;
void StylesRefresh();

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TTopFormStyles::TTopFormStyles(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner) {
    StylesRefresh;
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void StylesRefresh() {
    int i;
    string styleName;
    TopFormStyles->ListBox1->Items->Clear();
    i = 0;
    styleName = TStyleManager->StyleNames;
    styleName = styleName;
    // styleName in TStyleManager::StyleNames;
    while (styleName = TStyleManager::StyleNames. > "")
        do {
            TopFormStyles->ListBox1->Items->Add(styleName);
        }

}
```

An example of how to populate the list box would be greatly appreciated.

Any other improvements and recommendations are also welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

[`TStyleManager`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.Themes.TStyleManager) is a class, not an object.  `StyleNames` is a `static` property of that class, so you need to use `::` instead of `->` to access it.  And it returns an array of strings, which you are not enumerating correctly.

Try this:

TopFormStylesu.h:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef TopFormStylesuH
#define TopFormStylesuH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Forms.hpp>
//...
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TTopFormStyles : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TListBox *ListBox1;
    //...
private:    // User declarations
    void StylesRefresh();
    //...
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TTopFormStyles(TComponent* Owner);
    //...
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TTopFormStyles *TopFormStyles;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

TopFormStylesu.cpp:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "TopFormStylesu.h"
#include <Vcl.Themes.hpp>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"

TTopFormStyles *TopFormStyles;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TTopFormStyles::TTopFormStyles(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    StylesRefresh();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void TTopFormStyles::StylesRefresh()
{
    ListBox1->Items->BeginUpdate();
    try
    {
        ListBox1->Items->Clear();

        DynamicArray<String> styleNames = Vcl::Themes::TStyleManager::StyleNames;

        for(int i = 0; i < styleNames.Length; ++i)
        {
            String styleName = styleNames[i];
            ListBox1->Items->Add(styleName);
        }
    }
    __finally
    {
        ListBox1->Items->EndUpdate();
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: That did not seem to work.  The following error was generated:

[bcc64 Error] TopFormStylesu.cpp(24): expected a class or namespace

Comment: Remy I have updated the source code and the new listing has been posted as an update.  Do not hesitate to let me know what else is required.

Comment: @ArchBrooks perhaps instead update your question?  I think that is preferable.

Comment: ficuscr the only way is to update the question.  That is what I did.  The updated source was too large for the comments section.  What did I misunderstand?

Comment: Remy,

That did not work but the following errors were generated:

[bcc64 Error] TopFormStylesuo.cpp(20): use of undeclared identifier 'StylesRefresh'

[bcc64 Error] TopFormStylesuo.cpp(23): out-of-line definition of 'StylesRefresh' does not match any declaration in 'TTopFormStyles'

Comment: Look closely at my example.  I changed `StylesRefresh()` to be a method of the `TTopFormStyles` class (since half of its lines are accessing members of the class anyway).  You need to add a corresponding declaration in `TopFormStylesu.h`.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: This also failed.  Would it be possible to get an in the clear example of this.  It is not clear where the code goes with the //...  notations.

Comment: @ArchBrooks: The `//...` are just placeholders for any existing code you already have in those spots. I'm sorry, but do you really not know how to add a new method to an existing class?? This is basic 101 stuff.  In any case, I have updated my answer *again*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86730/discussion-between-arch-brooks-and-remy-lebeau).